# Form Sumbit action resulting into get request

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have simple form where on click of accpet button which of type resulting into GET requet rather than POST request. This is causing display of page twice and weired thing is form does generates POST request when you click on accept button again. This is mostly happening on IE8 and Chrome.

Current configuration :

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<title><spring:theme code="company"/><spring:theme code="title.companySetup.terms&conditions"></spring:theme></title>
<%-- <title><spring:message  code="userRegistration.addNewEmployer.title"></spring:message></title> --%>

 <!-- CONTENT START -->
    <div class="canvasWrapper">
        <div class="canvas" role="main">
            <div class="contentWrapper clearfix">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${whitelabellingfolder == 'ABC'}">
                <h1>Welcome to </h1>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test="${whitelabellingfolder == 'PQR'}">
                <h1 style="color:#6a2c91">Welcome to  <i style="color:#6a2c91">BOND</i></h1>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${whitelabellingfolder == 'XYZ'}">
                <h1>Welcome to </h1>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${whitelabellingfolder == 'LMN'}">
                <h1>Welcome to </h1>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${whitelabellingfolder == 'QWE'}">
                <h1>Welcome to </h1>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${whitelabellingfolder == 'POI'}">
                <h1>Welcome to </h1>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                <h1>Welcome to Nothing</h1>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>

              <h2>Terms and Conditions</h2>

                   <spring:message code="${whitelabellingfolder}.termsAndContion.body"></spring:message>

                     <form:form method="Post" commandName="userForm" >       
                     <form:errors path="*" cssClass="formError" element="div" />                                                                                        
                        <div class="ruler"></div>
                        <div class="navHolder clearfix">
                            <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
                                document.write('<div class="floatLeft"><input type="button" class="btnBlue" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()"></div>');
                            </script>  -->
                            <div class="floatRight"><input class="btnBlue" name="accpet" type="submit" value="Accept" /></div>                        
                            <div class="floatRight"><input class="btnBlue" name="decline" type="submit" value="Decline" /></div>
                        </div>

                </form:form> 

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT END -->
    <!-- FOOTER START -->
    <div class="footerWrapper2">
        <div class="footerCanvasWrapper">
            <div class="footerCanvas">&nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="footerLinks">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER END -->
```

Controller----

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.SessionThemeResolver;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/TNC.html")
public class TNCControllerAnn {

    private String className = "TNCControllerAnn";

    @Autowired
    private AppService appService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formbacking(@RequestHeader(value="Accept") String accept,
            @RequestHeader(value="Accept-Language") String acceptLanguage,
            @RequestHeader(value="User-Agent", defaultValue="foo") String userAgent,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        CMULogger.enter(className, "formBackingObject >> In the get method");
        String employerID = request.getHeader(UIConstant.EMP_ID);
        CMULogger.debug(className, " ** employerID: " + employerID);

        request.getSession().setAttribute(UIConstant.SELECTED_MODULE, "tnc");

        String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        if (!requestURL.endsWith("/")) {
            requestURL = requestURL.concat("/");
        }
        request.getSession().setAttribute(GlobalConstants.REQUEST_URL, requestURL);

        CMULogger.debug(className, " ** Request_URL: " + request.getSession().getAttribute(GlobalConstants.REQUEST_URL));

        ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
        UserContext userContext = new UserContext(employerID, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        serviceContext.setUserContext(userContext);

        RegistrationSetupAppResponse appResponse = null;
        try {
            appResponse = registrationAppService.getThemeChange(serviceContext);
        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AdviserDTO adviserDTO = appResponse.getAdviserDTO();
        String companyAgencyCode = adviserDTO.getCoLegalAgencyCode();
        Boolean isBranded = adviserDTO.isBrandedAccessRequired();
        String requestURI = "/";
        if (!isBranded) {
            companyAgencyCode = "sam";
        } else {
            requestURI = "/" + adviserDTO.getBrandingURL() + "/";
        }
        request.getSession().setAttribute(GlobalConstants.REQUEST_URI, requestURI);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("whitelabellingfolder", companyAgencyCode);
        WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, SessionThemeResolver.THEME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, companyAgencyCode);

        CMULogger.exit(className, "formBackingObject");
        return "termsnCondition";

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSumbit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        CMULogger.enter(className, "onSubmit >> In the post method");
        String redirectTo = GlobalConstants.REDIRECT;
        if (request.getParameter("accpet") != null) {
            String cnUserID = request.getHeader(UIConstant.CNUSER_ID);
            String email = request.getHeader(UIConstant.EMAIL);

            if ((email == null) || (cnUserID == null)) {
                String message = "Mandatory Field email or cnUserID is missing";
                CMULogger.error(className, "Exception in creating context", message);
               // throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }
            ServiceContext conext = new ServiceContext();
            UpdateTNCDTO updateTNCDTO = new UpdateTNCDTO();
            UpdateTNCRequest updateTNCRequest = new UpdateTNCRequest();

            updateTNCDTO.setCnUserID(cnUserID);
            updateTNCDTO.setEmail(email);
            updateTNCRequest.setUpdateTNCDTO(updateTNCDTO);

            try {
                 CMULogger.error(className, "Error******Error**** Before updating DB");
                registrationAppService.updateTNC(conext, updateTNCRequest);
                CMULogger.error(className, "Error******Error**** AFter updating DB");
            } catch (ApplicationException ae) {
                 CMULogger.error(className, "Error******Error**** Ocuured during updating DB");
                /*errors.reject("", ae.getMessage());
                try {
                    return showForm(request, errors, this.getFormView());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    CMULogger.error(className, e.getMessage());
                }*/
            }
            CMULogger.debug(className, "******" + PropertyReader.getEnvBasedProperty(GlobalConstants.TNC_ACCEPTED_URL));
            String requestURI = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(GlobalConstants.REQUEST_URI);
            redirectTo =
                    PropertyReader.getEnvBasedProperty(GlobalConstants.TNC_ACCEPTED_URL)
                            + ((requestURI.equals("/")) ? "" : requestURI.substring(0, (requestURI.length() - 1)));

        } else if (request.getParameter("decline") != null) {
            CMULogger.debug(className, "User declined T&C");
            StringBuilder strbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            strbuilder.append(redirectTo);
            strbuilder.append(PropertyReader.getEnvBasedProperty(GlobalConstants.LOGOFF_URL));
            String requestURI = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(GlobalConstants.REQUEST_URI);
            strbuilder.append("?advisor=" + ((requestURI.equals("/")) ? "" : requestURI.substring(1, (requestURI.length() - 1))));
            redirectTo = strbuilder.toString();
        }
        CMULogger.debug(className, "User is redirected to following url:" + redirectTo);
        CMULogger.exit(className, "onSubmit");
        //return "redirect:" + redirectTo;`enter code here`
        return redirectTo;


    }

    public AppService getAppService() {
        return appService;
    }

    public void setAppService(
            AppService appService) {
        this.appService = appService;
    }


}
```

Comment: There are too many things in your controller, and I cannot see where you load the model to initialize the form. Try to build a Minimal Verifiable Complete Example ...

Comment: Change `method="Post"` to `method="post"`, what happen?